# Getting the internal IP of an instance in an auto-scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using CloudFormation to bring up a single instance in an autoscaling group (MaxSize: 1)

I would like to know how to access the internal IP of that instance so I can assign it a friendly name with Route 53 in the same template.

If it were just a AWS::EC2::Instance it would be easy but it is defined as an autoscaling group so I don't have access to the "PrivateIP" attribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From CloudFormation, you can't.

Cloud Formation builds your auto scaling group, but it's scaling group itself that is responsible for creating that instance.  In some cases, Cloud Formation will have finished creating the stack prior to the scaling group triggering and completing the creation of the instance.

In order to achieve what you want through CloudFormation, you should add an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) to the front.  Then register the ELB address with Route 53, and tie that into the scaling group.

Answer (score 1):

from the instance, You can get the internal IP address as:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4/
```

Comment: I can't use this within my AWS::Route53::RecordSet to add an A record to this IP though.

Comment: Meaning, you want to retrieve the Internal IP address of the instance `ON-THE-FLY` via cloudformation so that you can feed it to your Route53 resource? IS this correct?

Comment: Precisely. I am already doing something similar with my external IP (an EIP assigned using Salt in the UserData section)

I'd also be happy getting the ec2-x-x-x-x.aws.amazon.com address so I can add a CNAME. The idea is I want to have foo.domain.com point to the external IP (EIP) and foo.internal.domain.com point to the internal IP.

Comment: Need to check [CloudFormation documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html) regarding how to pull instance metadata. There are few `cfn-*` scripts. Not sure whether they serve your purpose.

Comment: These look useful, but I'm not sure how to integrate them into a template: "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet"

...

"ResourceRecords": [ "internal ip address needs to be here" ]

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue, dont think its possible if your instance goes down and a new one comes up as it should using cloudfomration, You would have to run cloudformation update again as the private Ip would've changed

Comment: It's not possible at all, see the accepted answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).